# How can I access my Wordpress dashboard after receiving the following error message

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'wp_resource_hints' was given in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/ho/rs/ha/mywebsite.co.uk/public_html/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_removable_query_args() in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/ho/rs/ha/mywebsite.co.uk/public_html/blog/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 903
```

I have tried deactivating themes and plugins by temporarily renaming folder/files in my hosting cpanel, as suggested by others, but none of these methods have worked so far & I'm still locked out

I am using TwentyThirteen theme with Wordpress version 4.2.10

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like your wordpress installation either got corrupted or an install / upgrade went badly.

I'd try reinstalling WordPress over your existing files, being careful not to overwrite anything in /wp-content or the root file wp-config.php. Everything else you'll want to replace. Just to be safe, it wouldn't hurt to make a backup of everything in the WordPress installation before you do this. :)

Comment: Thanks Greg

I'm not sure how to reinstall Wordpress without overwriting the existing wp-content & wp-config files... can you explain how to accomplish this please, as I'm a newbie

Thanks again - James

Comment: The answer depends a lot on what server / hosting you're running on, but basically, you'd want to use an FTP program that allows you to drag and drop files from your local machine to your remote site. You'll want to snag a fresh copy of WordPress from WordPress.org, unzip it on your computer, and then upload all the files from the root folder of the fresh copy to the server *except wp-config.php*. Then, upload the entire contents of the wp-admin and wp-includes folders to the same folder on your site. Do not upload anything in the wp-content folder.

Comment: Did you have any luck with the reinstall?